# Connecting java to SQL Server 2014

Tags: java, sql-server, connection

I've been having these problem for 2 straight days. I wanna cry lol.
Anyway, I have Java 1.8, an Eclipse and SQL Server 2014.

I've tried using JDBC ODBC and ucanaccess but it still gives me an error.
Here is my code in ucanaccess:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    try
    {

        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\login_DB");
        Statement stment = conn.createStatement();
        String qry = "SELECT * FROM tblGender";

        ResultSet rs = stment.executeQuery(qry);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String id    = rs.getString("username") ;
            String pssword= rs.getString("password");

            System.out.println(id + pssword);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }



}
```

and I get this error :

```
given file does not exist: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\login_DB
```

Any suggestion? For more info on my problem just ask D:. I hope 
you'll be patient on handling me xD

Comment: Is file really present ? Are you missing file extension e.g. ".db" etc.?

Comment: @KaushikLele I have a created a database file via Query in SQL Server. I right clicked on my database file, clicked properties and look for the path. I copy pasted it and add  "//login_DB" because it is the name of my db. My database's extension file is ".mdf"

Comment: @KaushikLele UPDATE!!!! I try being specific on my file. added ".mdf" at the end of my "login_DB" but I get this error

'Decoding not supported.  Please choose a CodecProvider which supports reading the current database encoding.'

Comment: Ucanaccess supports Microsoft Access database.  SQL Server is not supported.

Comment: @saka1029 is Microsoft Access Database and Microsoft Access Database  Engine Redistributable the same?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that.